# Converting to international charater doesnt work with jsonobject.tostring but works with string literal?

Tags: java, android, json

This doesnt convert to `å`

```
String j_post = new String((byte[]) j_posts.getJSONObject(i).get("tagline").toString().getBytes("utf-8"), "utf-8");
```

but the following does

```
String j_post = new String((byte[]) "\u00e5".getBytes("utf-8"), "utf-8");
```

How do i fix this?

UPDATE: Now i tried fixing the encoding before i cast it as JSONObject and it still doesnt work.

```
json = new JSONObject(new String((byte[]) jsonContent.getBytes("utf-8"), "utf-8"));

    JSONArray j_posts = json.getJSONArray("posts");
    for (int i = 0; i<j_posts.length();i++){
        //[String(byte[] data)][2]
        String j_post =j_posts.getJSONObject(i).get("tagline").toString();
        post_data.add(new Post(j_post));
    }
```

Please note that i am getting a string as a response from my web-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your JSON doesn't have the character in the required format. Look into the code, where the JSON is prepared and include the `UTF-8` encoding there, when the JSON is formed.

Comment: I am doing something wrong when submitting the data. Though i couldnt get my code working but this seems like a reasonable answer. Thanks for your time. I will update this thread if i figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
String j_post = new String((byte[]) "\u00e5".getBytes("utf-8"), "utf-8");
```

indeed is (better):

```
String j_post = "\u00e5";
```

And hence

```
String j_post = new String((byte[]) j_posts.getJSONObject(i).get("tagline")
        .toString().getBytes("utf-8"), "utf-8");
```

is

```
String j_post = j_posts.getJSONObject(i).get("tagline").toString();
```

So @RJ is right, and the data is mangled: either in getting or sending (wrong encoding).